# Setting the width of a variable in applescript

Tags: applescript

I am trying to write an apple script that sequentially names my TV shows with "S0XEYY" where YY is a two digit number. I have the following:

```
tell application "iTunes"
     set p to selection
          set c to count of p's items
          set fixed indexing to true
        repeat with i from 1 to c
            set t to item i of p
            try
                set the episode number of t to i
                set the episode ID of t to "S" & (text returned of a) & "E" & i
                set the season number of t to text returned of a
            end try
        end repeat
```

However, I need the

> (text returned of a)

as well as

> i

to be of width 2, padded with a 0. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I went about it:

```
if i ≤ 9 then
    set the episode ID of t to episode ID of t & "0" & i
else
    set the episode ID of t to episode ID of t & i
```

which I am sure is not the best way to do it, because it assumes no more then 2 characters are needed, but its the best solution I have, which works for this application because TV seasons never (that I have seen) exceed 20-30 episodes.